# unable to show emoji's properly in UIlabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, emoji

I am trying to save the emojis to server and on later time receiving them.

I used the Following Code before

```
NSData *data = [strEmo dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *data1 = [strEmo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

It generates the Hashcode for the Emoji. But decoding doesn't work. So I skipped the Idea of using this Code.

Then I used a third Party NSString+HTML.h Class. Which Sends and recieve emoji easily. But
Now the Problem is when there are so many emoji's the UIlabel on which I am showing the data, the emojis are distorted and If I saved 20 emojis it shows 12-13 only.

I have added the Pic for reference
[image]

where Yellow part is UIlabel with back colored Yellow

Comment: Please provide goodValue nslog output from console window.

Comment: on console it gives all the Emojis corrently, its On UIlabel its showing like this. am adding Console output. EDITING

Comment: Can you please give your console output here with question?

Comment: Why do encode using lossy ASCII encoding and decode using UTF8 encoding?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I dont' now. Just got the Snippet and Checked it. IS there any mistake, Can you provide me little code for that

Comment: 1. You took a piece of code that you hadn't  understood and put it in your code causing a problem that you do not understand. Your suggested solution is to get another piece of code that you do not understand to put it in your code. What do you think about that strategy? 2. First of all: Change `NSLossyASCIIStringEncoding` into `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad when One has to deliever the Project, One cannot do much.

Comment: @Mrunal when I try to paste the out put it shows boxes over stackoverflow

Comment: Indeed, one should learn basics of Objective-C and Cocoa before starting a project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67201/discussion-between-jeev-and-amin-negm-awad).

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I am learning. And If one piece of code is not working for me it doesnt mean I should Stop over here and go for Basics

Answer (score 0):

Buddy why are you changing the string in Data two times in a row just simply use this

```
NSString *uniText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[strEmo UTF8String]];
NSData *msgData = [uniText dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *readyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:msgData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

First convert your string into constant C characters then convert it into string using UTF8 encoding, now convert it into `NSData` as (7-bit verbose ASCII to represent all Unicode characters) using `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` encoding and then again string ready to send with `unicode characters`. Hope this should work as it is working fine in my code.